# Unreachable Return-Statement?

Tags: java, xml, recursion

Just got a question concerning a return statement in Java and the use of a method which should return a value from deep within a xml-statement.

```
public static String searchNode(Node node, Node parent, String nodeResult) {
    String nodeValue = "";

    if (node.hasChildNodes()) {
        NodeList childrens = node.getChildNodes();
        for (int i = 0; i < childrens.getLength(); i++) {
            searchNode(childrens.item(i), node, nodeResult);
        }
    } else {
        nodeValue = node.getNodeValue().trim();
        if (nodeValue.length() > 0) {
            if (parent.getNodeName().equals(nodeResult)) {
                System.out.println("YESSA: " + nodeValue);
                return "2: " + nodeValue;
            }
        }
    }
    return nodeValue;
}
```

And here's my question: Why is the return "2"-Statement never reached? Or let me rather ask: why is nodeValue at the end still empty? I tested it already and the code prints this "System.out.println"-thing, but never reaches the return there?!
What do I have to change if I wanted the nodeValue filled in the value from the "else"-statement?

EDIT:

Ok, I tried out what you proposed but unfortunately I never get the result I wanted to have.
Further description:

I have a xml-structure which looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<log>
<published>2014-03-28T15:28:36.646Z</published>
<actor>
    <objectType>person</objectType>
    <id>e1b8948f-321e-78ca-d883-80500aae71b5</id>
    <displayName>anonymized</displayName>
</actor>
<verb>update</verb>
<object>
    <objectType>concept</objectType>
    <id>a1ad6ace-c722-ffa9-f58e-b4169acdb4e3</id>
    <content>time</content>
</object>
<target>
    <objectType>conceptMap</objectType>
    <id>4b8f69e3-2914-3a1a-454e-f4c157734bd1</id>
    <displayName>my first concept map</displayName>
</target>
<generator>
    <objectType>application</objectType>
    <url>http://www.golabz.eu/content/go-lab-concept-mapper</url>
    <id>c9933ad6-dd4a-6f71-ce84-fb1676ea3aac</id>
    <displayName>ut.tools.conceptmapper</displayName>
</generator>
<provider>
    <objectType>ils</objectType>
    <url>http://graasp.epfl.ch/metawidget/1/b387b6f</url>
    <id>10548c30-72bd-0bb3-33d1-9c748266de45</id>
    <displayName>unnamed ils</displayName>
</provider>
</log>
```

I do the method call as I show you in the following:

```
searchNode(document.getFirstChild(), null, "id")
```

Then, I want to save the id-value of the subnode `<id>` from `<actor>` in a variable (after that the method should terminate with something like a `break;`, because I don't want to get all ID's. Just this single ID.

Comment: if `System.out.println("YESSA: " + nodeValue);` is executed then `return "2: " + nodeValue;` is also executed...

Comment: That's not the case. The `System.out.println` is executed, but the only return which is executed is the last one which does not contain the `return 2: " + nodeValue`. Finally this method returns a value which is empty though. :-/

Comment: You never use the return value of `searchNode` in your `if` case...

Comment: @X-Fate What you describe is not possible.

Answer (score 2):

You don't return the result of your recursing. You should return it, or set the result.

```
return searchNode(childrens.item(i), node, nodeResult);
```

or
    nodeValue = searchNode(childrens.item(i), node, nodeResult);

Comment: This is wrong - it will never search children past the first one, returning unconditionally after checking the first branch.

Comment: That was a good proposal, but this method you mentioned returns the value of the **last** node. My problem is that I have to get the value from the node which is called "nodeResult". Unfortunately - in most cases from the xml-document - that's not the last node. :-/

Comment: Sorry, as dasblinkenlight said it returns the first. My fault.

Answer (score 1):

You wrote a recursive method that ignores results of intermediate invocations. The return statement in question would be reached only if you start your search right at the node that you want to find.

To fix this, your recursive branch should pay attention to what's returned by recursive invocation. If you need to find the first matching child, do this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < childrens.getLength(); i++) {
    String tmp = searchNode(childrens.item(i), node, nodeResult);
    if (tmp != null && tmp.length() != 0) {
        return tmp;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are calling the method recursively, and each call creates its own `nodeValue` on the stack. Consider this:

- first you call it with the node that has one child, `nodeValue` is empty string
- then, in the first `for` loop you call the same method again, new `nodeValue` is created on the stack
- you return `2: something` from it
- you do nothing with that return result, just return empty string in the original call

Now, you probably want to use the result from recursive calls, so try this in the `for` loop

```
nodeValue = searchNode(childrens.item(i), node, nodeResult);
```